# How can I add an HTML file that references other JS files in Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, html, file, insert, google-sites

I was trying to set up a page on Google Sites to show of my work with some HTML canvas games I made. However, Google Sites' "Insert HTML" option is severely limited, it only lets you enter HTML code that has no external dependencies to work. As you can imagine, the kind of things I want to upload have textures, audio and multiple js files scattered throughout the code. All js files are referenced on the main HTML file, but this isn't working, it isn't picking up the other files and it's just showing a white screen.

Here is all of the HTML code (as you can imagine, 99% of the work is JS):

```
<html>

<div id="canvas_div_no_cursor">
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800"
height="600"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('canvas_div_no_cursor').style.cursor = "none";
</script>

<script src="js/classes.js"></script>
<script src="js/HUD.js"></script>
<script src="js/movement.js"></script>
<script src="js/gameplay.js"></script>
<script src="js/graphics.js"></script>
<script src="js/input.js"></script>
<script src="js/audio.js"></script>
<script src="js/Main.js"></script>

</html>
```

That's about it, all the rest of the code in in those referenced js files. Yes, I uploaded the whole folder to Drive, and even tried importing the html through there, it won't even let me. I searched online to no avail, does anyone have a clue to how I can do this? The only viable option I see is to transfer all the code from the files to the single HTMl file, but I don't even know if it would accept other calls such as .mp3 files and .png files.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do this, at least not right now. My solution is to put the code in an S3 bucket, and make that the src.

Comment: @PBurke Didn't know about that, thanks. Since this question is rather old, I had already found a solution. Similar to yours, but I used google drive instead of Amazon. You upload the files you want to Google Drive, share them with a link and then paste the link in this website: https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/ You can use the output as the source and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the needed files to Google Drive and get a directo download link to them with [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/). Once you have that, simply change the `src` with the direct link and it should import it.

Comment: This is NOT working for me. I wonder why.                                                                     
```<script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=BLA-BLA-BLA"</script>```  NO GOOD 
```<script src="typeahead-0.11.1.js"> </script>``` OK

Comment: When I opened the link in Chrome I got the following message: "Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses.

This file is executable and may harm your computer. typeahead-0.11.1.js (92k)

[Download anyway] <- button"

Comment: Did you make the files public?  Running in the browser is likely anon sans credentials for your private drive.